# $\nabla \vec{v}$ in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the outer product of $\nabla$ with a vector $\vec{v}$ in cylindrical coordinates. I know that in cylindrical coordinates $$\nabla = \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bigg)$$

So then if $\vec{v} = (0,v(r),0)$ would $$\nabla \vec{v} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\\frac{\partial v}{\partial r} & 0 &0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Your best bet is to start with Cartesian coordinates and change variables. The reason I make that recommendation is because I'm not confident that you can get the right formulae for $\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$ or $\nabla \times \vec{v}$.

If you insist on using curvilinear coordinates, and what you want is genuinely the gradient of the components, then the problem you're running into is that the basis vectors are functions of the coordinates. In cylindrical coordinates the basis vectors, in terms of and invariant cartesian basis, are:
$$\begin{align}
\hat{r} & = \cos\phi \hat{i} + \sin\phi \hat{j},\\
\hat{\phi} & = -\sin\phi \hat{i} + \cos\phi \hat{j}. \end{align}$$

When you want to calculate a quantity like $\nabla \vec{v}$ you have to take this into account:$$\begin{align}
\nabla \vec{v} & = \nabla ( v_r \hat{r} + v_\phi \hat{\phi} ) + \hat{k} \nabla v_z \\
& = (\nabla v_r) \hat{r} + v_r (\nabla \hat{r}) + (\nabla v_\phi) \hat{\phi} + v_\phi (\nabla \hat{\phi}) +  \nabla v_z \hat{k}.
\end{align}$$
From the definition of the basis vectors, we get the only non-vanishing derivatives of the bases:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat{r}}{\partial \phi} & = \hat{\phi} \\
\frac{\partial \hat{\phi}}{\partial \phi} & = -\hat{r}. \end{align}$$
Applying these to the gradient gives:
$$\begin{align}
\nabla \vec{v} & = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{r}\otimes & \hat{\phi}\otimes & \hat{z}\otimes \end{array}\right]  \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r} \\
\frac{1}{r} \left(\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \phi} -  v_\phi \right)  & \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial \phi} + v_r\right) & \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \phi} \\
\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial v_\phi}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z} 
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}
\hat{r} \\
\hat{\phi} \\
 \hat{z}\end{array}\right]\end{align},$$
in the cylindrical basis.

Comment: What is $\nabla v_r$? Partial of $v$ w.r.t $r$?

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates: $$\nabla v_r = \left[\hat{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} + \frac{\hat{\phi}}{r} \frac{\partial}{ \partial \phi} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right] v_r ,  $$
and $v_r \equiv \hat{r} \cdot \vec{v}$.

Comment: Is this giving a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Yes. I didn't write the tensor product symbols because you didn't write any in the question. The basis for the tensor are the tensor products of the basis vectors. For example, the radial-radial component is the coefficient of $\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r}$, and the radial-azimuthal component is $\hat{r}\otimes \hat{\phi}$ (note that this is not the same as $\hat{\phi}\otimes \hat{r}$ because tensor products do not commute).

Comment: By $\hat {r} \hat {r}$ do you mean $\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r}$

Comment: Yes. I just placed the full matrix in the answer.